# Handling uncaught exceptions from bound MVVM properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to handle all uncaught Exceptions in my WPF application.

I created a dummy project and changed the App.xaml.cs to look like this

```
public partial class App : Application
{ 
    public App()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test1");
        };

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test2");
        };

        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test3");
        };

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test4");
        };
    }
}
```

I also have this ViewModel and property called TestProp which I have bound to a TextBox.Text in XAML:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    private string testProp;

    public string TestProp
    {
        get => testProp;
        set
        {
            testProp = value;

            // RAISE EXCEPTION IN PROPERTY SETTER
            throw new Exception("Test Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Changing that property in the View will throw the exception, however none of the events in App.xaml.cs will get triggered, except for the FirstChanceException.

The problem with FirstChanceException, is it will get raised, even if I handle the Exception in code.

I simply want all Unhandled Exceptions to get handled globally so I can log the error and display an error dialog box, without having to wrap every getter/setter with try/catch's.

Is this possible?  Thank you

Comment: Can you try subscribing not in the constructor, but in OnStartup()?

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski thanks for the response.  I just tried that, and same results :(.  FirstChanceException is the only one hit.

Comment: Is it Core or Framework? Which versions? I'm really curious what's going on - I've been testing exceptions handling on UI thread today (.NET Framework) and it simply works.

Comment: .NET Framework.  I tried it from a bare-bones, new project to make sure I wasn't going crazy lol.  If I throw that Exception in the constructor - or set that property elsewhere it will hit those events.  It's only when I set the property from the View that it doesn't seem to hit any events except the "FirstChanceException".  My debugger will stop on the `throw`, however it won't bubble up to the events in App.xaml.cs

Comment: Could you publish your example app on Github?

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski yes, thanks for looking at it.  Here is the github: https://github.com/aplocher/WpfApp3/tree/master/WpfApp3 (note, my "TestViewModel" class is in the MainWindow.xaml.cs).  The only exception that gets hit is that "FirstChanceException" ("test4")

Comment: This works OK. I catch several FirstChanceExceptions, then all the rest 
(Test4
Test7
Test6
Test1
Test3
Test5)

Comment: When you set the property from the VIew?  (changing the Textbox.Text)?

Comment: I've uncommented commented lines in MainWindow constructor. I was testing under the debugger. If you'd like to test in release you may want to handle these exceptions not to have the application terminated.

Comment: Yes, those will get caught in those events, but I'm trying to get ALL uncaught exceptions (mainly, bound properties in the UI).  So if you change the TextBox in the View, those events never get raised.  That's the problem I'm trying to solve right now...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible. You must implement the App.DispatcherUnhandledException event.
Review [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception?view=netframework-4.8) article for show you how to implement it.

=============================================

UPDATE 1:
Yes, as @Maciek Świszczowski mentioned in the comment, you had already implemented it in your initial code, it was my mistake not to notice it.

The problem you have is that throwing exceptions within a class that is used as view model goes to the WPF validation system. This feature is known as "Validation on the Data Object", and the exception not goes to the App.DispatcherUnhandledException event, but goes within the WPF validation system.

One way to make exceptions thrown in Data Object notifications are handled globally in the App.DispatcherUnhandledException is to make them bubble up to the top of the application. In code, it could be accomplished by adding the ExceptionValidationRule class in the binding to the property, and throwing the exception inside the Validation.error attached event, something like this:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp10.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800" Height="450"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:TestViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Validation.Error="Validation_OnError">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding NotifyOnValidationError="True" Path="TestProp" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <ExceptionValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and in the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new TestViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;
        //throw new Exception("Test2 Exception");
    }

    private void Validation_OnError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e) {
        throw e.Error.Exception;
    }
}
```

I tested the code [here](https://github.com/marlonedu/WpfTests/tree/master/WpfApp10)

Comment: Isn't that the same that subscribing to Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException, which is already done?

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski I believe so, yes.  Just to be safe, I tried adding `DispatcherUnhandledException="App_DispatcherUnhandledException"` to the `<Application>` tag in App.xaml (just to verify), and it's still not working

Comment: Yes, sorry for the initial answer. I edit my answer. Let me know if this can help you @AdamPlocher

Comment: I'm tested the implementation, but it seems like work for the first time, but no for the second time?